# Applying a coupon in WooCommerce cart page doesn't refresh totals

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently working on implementing AJAX functionality on my WooCommerce cart.php page. The goal is to enable users to apply coupons without refreshing the entire page. While I've made progress, I'm encountering a roadblock – the applied coupons aren't updating the cart totals as expected.

Screenshot of the issue:

[image: picture]

cart.php coupon form:

```
        <?php if ( wc_coupons_enabled() ) { ?>
        <form class="checkout_coupon mb-0" method="post">
            <h1 class="cart-small-title">Discount Code</h1>
            <div class="main_cou_nav">
                <p class="cc_code">Coupon Code</p>
                <div class="coupon">
                    <h3 class="widget-title"><?php echo get_flatsome_icon( 'icon-tag' ); ?> <?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3><label for="coupon_code" class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Coupon:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label><input type="text" name="coupon_code" class="input-text" id="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Enter Your Coupon code', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> <button type="button" class="is-form expand button<?php if ( fl_woocommerce_version_check( '7.0.1' ) ) { echo esc_attr( wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) ? ' ' . wc_wp_theme_get_element_class_name( 'button' ) : '' ); } ?>" id="apply_coupon" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                  <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                  <div id="custom-coupon-notice"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>


        <?php } ?>
```

functions.php:

```
function enqueue_my_custom_script() {
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'ajax-script-cart', // Handle for your script
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-cart.js', // Path to your script
    array('jquery'), // Dependencies (jQuery as an example)
    '6.0.0', // Version number
    true // Load in the footer
  );

  wp_localize_script(
    'ajax-script-cart', // Handle for your script
    'wc_cart_params', // Name for the JavaScript object
    array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) // Data to pass to the script
  );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_custom_script');


function ajax_apply_coupon_cart() {
  if(!isset($_POST['coupon_code']) || empty($_POST['coupon_code'])) {
    wp_send_json(['success' => false, 'data' => ['message' => 'No coupon code provided']], 200);
    return;
  }

  $coupon_code = sanitize_text_field($_POST['coupon_code']);

  if(!WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon_code)) {
    $coupon_id = wc_get_coupon_id_by_code($coupon_code);

    if(!$coupon_id) {
      wp_send_json(['success' => false, 'data' => ['message' => sprintf(__('Coupon  does not exist!', 'woocommerce'), $coupon_code)]], 200);
      return;
    }

    WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon_code);
    wp_send_json_success(['message' => sprintf(__('Coupon  applied successfully.', 'woocommerce'), $coupon_code)], 200);
  } else {
    wp_send_json_error(['message' => sprintf(__('Coupon  is already applied!', 'woocommerce'), $coupon_code)], 200);
  }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_apply_coupon_cart', 'ajax_apply_coupon_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_apply_coupon_cart', 'ajax_apply_coupon_cart');
```

custom-ajax.js:

```
console.log("Cart script is working")

jQuery(document).on('click', '#apply_coupon', function () {
  console.log("button working as well")
  var code = jQuery('#coupon_code').val();

  data = {
    action: 'ajax_apply_coupon_cart',
    coupon_code: code
  };

  jQuery.post(wc_cart_params.ajax_url, data, function (returned_data) {
    console.log("Data returned from server: ", returned_data); // Log returned data for debugging.
    if(returned_data.success) {
      jQuery('#custom-coupon-notice').html(returned_data.data.message).removeClass('woocommerce-error').addClass('woocommerce-message').show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#custom-coupon-notice').html(returned_data.data.message).removeClass('woocommerce-message').addClass('woocommerce-error').show();
    }
    jQuery(document.body).trigger('updated_wc_div'); // Update the cart page after applying the coupon
  })
    .fail(function (jqXHR) {
      console.error(jqXHR); // Log the entire jqXHR object for debugging.
      var errorData = jqXHR.responseJSON;
      var errorMessage = errorData && errorData.message ? errorData.message : 'An unknown error occurred';
      jQuery('#custom-coupon-notice').html(errorMessage).addClass('woocommerce-error').show();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, in WooCommerce, coupon applied in cart is already made via AJAX, so normally the page never get reloaded (same thing when removing a coupon or cart item, and also when updating quantities.

In your case, you may have done too many customizations, so the default AJAX process is not enabled anymore.

**So the following may not work if Ajax cart refresh has been unintentionally disabled by you.**

In your code, maybe [`calculate_totals()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1391-L1409) method is missing, to allow triggering cart calculations update.

```php
function ajax_apply_coupon_cart() {
    if(!isset($_POST['coupon_code']) || empty($_POST['coupon_code'])) {
        wp_send_json(['success' => false, 'data' => ['message' => 'No coupon code provided']], 200);
        // return; // <== Not needed as wp_send_json() throws die();
    }
    $coupon_code = sanitize_text_field($_POST['coupon_code']);
  
    if(!WC()->cart->has_discount($coupon_code)) {
        $coupon_id = wc_get_coupon_id_by_code($coupon_code);
    
        if(!$coupon_id) {
            wp_send_json(['success' => false, 'data' => ['message' => sprintf(__('Coupon  does not exist!', 'woocommerce'), $coupon_code)]], 200);
            // return; // <== Not needed as wp_send_json() throws die();
        }
    
        $result = WC()->cart->apply_coupon($coupon_code); // Apply coupon
        
        if( $result ) {
            WC()->cart->calculate_totals(); // <=== Refresh totals (Missing)

            wp_send_json_success(['message' => sprintf(__('Coupon  applied successfully.', 'woocommerce'), $coupon_code)], 200);
        }
    } else {
        wp_send_json_error(['message' => sprintf(__('Coupon  is already applied!', 'woocommerce'), $coupon_code)], 200);
    }
}
add_action('wp_ajax_ajax_apply_coupon_cart', 'ajax_apply_coupon_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_apply_coupon_cart', 'ajax_apply_coupon_cart');
```

If Ajax cart refresh is still working, this should solve the issue.

Comment: I will try your solution, but how is default functionality in woocommerce like that triggered?

Comment: All cart page available actions are Ajax powered by default in WooCommerce… To see that, first make a database backup… Then upload the Free Storefront theme and enable it… Then add a product, go to cart and add a coupon. Now you can see that fact.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your answer, anyway it didn't work by default, because flatsome theme put coupon code inside form tag in cart.php